# How do I make a tip calculator with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following a course to do javascript projects on udemy and one is this tip calculator. I can put in the bill and the percentage but it does not calculate the tip amount or the total.

I have tried changing the form to a div tag. I tried adding `action = "javascript:void(calculate())"`. I tried adding in in the Number function so that `var tip = Number(amount) * (Number(percentage)/100);`
I ran it in a couple of browsers and I can't get the calculated results.

```js
function calculate() {
  var amount = $('#amount').val();
  var percentage = $('#percentage').val();
  var tip = amount * (percentage / 100);
  var total = Number(amount) + tip;

  $('#tip').val(tip.toFixed(2));
  $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

$('#calculator').submit(calculate);
```

```css
#calculator {
  background-color: #273a63;
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 55px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#addup {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 120px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1f80c9;
}

#perc {
  color: #cd5c5c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span id="perc">Tip </span> Calculator</h1>
<form action="javascript:void(calculate())" id="calculator">
  <p>Bill Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
  <p>Percentage Tip: <input id="percentage" /></p>
  <p>Tip Amount: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
  <p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
  <p> <input id="addup" type="submit" value="Calculate" /> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: you do not cancel the submit action. look into preventDeafult

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: It works fine in the snippet. You just have a typo in the HTML. It should be `<script src="https://...">` and not `<script> src = "https://...` You can delete the question as it was just a typo

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in the CodePen: `<script> src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```js
function calculate() {
  var amount = $('#amount').val();
  var percentage = $('#percentage').val();
  var tip = amount * (percentage / 100);
  var total = Number(amount) + tip;

  $('#tip').val(tip.toFixed(2));
  $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

$('#calculator').submit(calculate);
```

```css
#calculator {
  background-color: #273a63;
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 55px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-size: 35px;
}

#addup {
  background-color: #cc0000;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 120px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1f80c9;
}

#perc {
  color: #cd5c5c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="percentage calculator">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device - width, initial-scale = 1">
  <title>Tip Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="perc">Tip </span> Calculator</h1>
  <form action="javascript:void(calculate())" id="calculator">
    <p>Bill Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
    <p>Percentage Tip: <input id="percentage" /></p>
    <p>Tip Amount: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
    <p> <input id="addup" type="submit" value="Calculate" /> </p>
  </form>

  <script>
    src = "myscript.js"
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please mention the typos in the comments. They should be closed and deleted as they add no long term value to the site

Answer (score -1):

Additionally you need to prevent the form from submitting, by using [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/#event-preventDefault) in your `calculate` function.

Small working code example:

```js
function calculate(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var amount = $('#amount').val();
  var percentage = $('#percentage').val();
  var tip = amount * (percentage / 100);
  var total = Number(amount) + tip;

  $('#tip').val(tip.toFixed(2));
  $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

$('#calculator').submit(calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><span id="perc">Tip </span> Calculator</h1>
<form id="calculator">
  <p>Bill Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
  <p>Percentage Tip: <input id="percentage" /></p>
  <p>Tip Amount: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
  <p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
  <p> <input id="addup" type="submit" value="Calculate" /> </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

After adding the jquery library like pointed before, here are the code changes I would suggest: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qeawNG .

On the  section, the code I would namely remove the event from the form submit, and just add later a click event on the button, which should change from submit to button.

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="" id="calculator">
   <p>Bill Amount: <input id = "amount" /></p>
   <p>Percentage Tip: <input id = "percentage" /></p>
   <p>Tip Amount: <input id = "tip" disabled = "disabled" /></p>
   <p>Total: <input id = "total" disabled = "disabled" /></p>
   <p> <input id="addup" type="button" value="Calculate" /> </p>
</form>
```

JS code :

```
function calculate(){
   var amount = $('#amount').val();
   var percentage = $('#percentage').val();
   var tip = amount * (percentage/100);
   var total = Number(amount) + tip;

   $('#tip').val(tip.toFixed(2));
   $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
}

$('#addup').click(calculate);
```

P.S: I chose to remove the submit code, because it would require that you would add a onsubmit return false, in order for the form to not submit and that you could stay on this page, otherwise submit would make you go to a new page and the form would be reset, and therefore you would never see a result.
It's of course doable with the onsubmit return false, but I thing would be more complicated. Below you can see the code with this functionality :

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="" id="calculator" onsubmit="return calculate()">
   <p>Bill Amount: <input id = "amount" /></p>
   <p>Percentage Tip: <input id = "percentage" /></p>
   <p>Tip Amount: <input id = "tip" disabled = "disabled" /></p>
   <p>Total: <input id = "total" disabled = "disabled" /></p>
   <p> <input id="addup" type="submit" value="Calculate" /> </p>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function calculate(){
   var amount = $('#amount').val();
   var percentage = $('#percentage').val();
   var tip = amount * (percentage/100);
   var total = Number(amount) + tip;

   $('#tip').val(tip.toFixed(2));
   $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

According to the console, the codepen is missing a JQuery reference. More specifically, it's saying "$ is undefined".
Go to settings, and under the JS tab, add the JQuery library.